# Duplicate ID after postback -> invalid postback

Tags: asp.net, webforms, asp.net-ajax, postback

I have the following situation:

I have a page containing a listview placeholder with controls that are added to the page dynamically. I can change these controls via a postBack, where the placeholder is exchanged. However, it happens that some of the controls before the postBack changing the whole control have the same ID as some controls in the new content of the placeholder.
This leads to a PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Invalid postback or callback argument.

What can I do to avoid that the IDs lead to this exception.

I do NOT want to turn event validation off and unfortunately it is not possible to change the IDs of the controls either.

Thanks for your help!

```
<asp:ListView ID="rows" runat="server" OnSorting="rows_sort" OnItemCreated="rows_created" OnDataBound="rows_databound">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <div>
            <table id="editGrid">
                <thead>
                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="header" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr><asp:PlaceHolder ID="columns" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder></tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="noData" OnInit="noData_Init" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

And the code creating the controls (where some of them may have the same ID).

```
protected void noData_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PlaceHolder phNoDat = (PlaceHolder)sender;

    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table tbl = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table();
    tbl.ID = "editGrid";
    tbl.ClientIDMode = System.Web.UI.ClientIDMode.Static;

    TableHeaderRow thr, thrFilter;
    buildHeader(out thr, out thrFilter); // Create filter controls (e.g. dropdown, textbox) which are then added to the rows

    tbl.Controls.Add(thr);
    tbl.Controls.Add(thrFilter);
    phNoDat.Controls.Add(tbl);

    topToolBar.Visible = true;
}
```

The buildHeader method:

```
private void buildHeader(out TableHeaderRow thr, out TableHeaderRow thrFilter)
{
    thr = new TableHeaderRow();
    thrFilter = new TableHeaderRow();
    thrFilter.ID = "thFilterRow";

    TableHeaderCell thc = new TableHeaderCell();
    thc.Height = new Unit("32px");

    LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
    lb.ID = "header_" + ColumnName;
    lb.CommandName = "Sort";
    lb.CommandArgument = ColumnName;
    lb.Text = "";
    Literal lit = new Literal();
    lit.Text = "<div style=\"min-width: " + colWidth + "px\"><div class=\"pull-left\">" + DisplayName + "</div><i class=\"" + sortIcon + " pull-right\" style=\"padding-top: 3px;\">&nbsp;</i></div>";
    lb.Controls.Add(lit);
    thc.Controls.Add(lb);

    thr.Controls.Add(thc);

    DropDownList cbValSel;
    HiddenField hfIsLookup;
    string def = null;

    /* ... */

    thcFilter.Controls.Add(cbValSel);

    thrFilter.Controls.Add(thcFilter);

    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: You should share some scaled down version of your code.

Comment: please share some code.

Comment: I'd try to comment the code line -  tbl.ClientIDMode = System.Web.UI.ClientIDMode.Static;

Comment: Thanks, but no, that is not the problem. The IDs of controls in the table are in conflict. They must be saved somewhere and I would like to "clear this storage".